# How to make a systemctl service not close other services

Tags: apache, service, dependencies

Below is the BHd.service file; this is the first time I've done this, and everything is finally working perfectly except that when I stop the service, it always without fail stops httpd (and likely other services listed here). I sincerely have looked everywhere for the answer. I don't think it should be doing this.

**Log story short, I need smb, nfs, httpd and mariadb to be running before this unit start. I do not want them to be stopped after the unit is stopped or reloaded; for now, firewalld must be off.** I honestly can't tell what line is affecting the systemctl stop command, everything I read indicates that Requires and After only affect systemctl start.

```
[Unit]
Description=BH
Documentation=somewhere.com
Wants=smb.service nfs.service
After=httpd.service mariadb.service
Requires=httpd.service mariadb.service
Conflicts=firewalld.service

[Service]
Type=forking
PIDFile=/var/run/BHd.pid
ExecStart=/usr/bin/python /var/www/html/pythonscripts/BHd.py start
ExecStop=/usr/bin/python /var/www/html/pythonscripts/BHd.py stop

[Install]
Alias=BHd
WantedBy=smb.service nfs.service
RequiredBy=httpd.service mariadb.service
```

EDIT: More info

```
[root@BHDEMO ~]# systemctl -l | grep BH
BHd.service                                                                              loaded failed failed    Description
[root@BHDEMO ~]#
```

Answer (score 0):

**Short Answer: systemctl disable BHd**

**Long Answer:**
Well, I feel stupid... I'm sure some of you will think "this guy is writing a 40k line service but didn't know that!"... yes, that's how us computer engineers roll, lol.

The Solution:
After editing this file over and over in an attempt to get it working, I never tried systemctl disable BHd... that did it... I had a few lines in the Install section early, WantedBy and RequiredBy as seen above. I realized about 5 hours ago that this was not correct and deleted it. Unfortunately, just doing another enable is not sufficient, as those lines created directories that needed to be uninstalled with disable, then reinstalled with enabled without the added files and folders. Almost sounds like a linux bug that should be fixed, imagine how many like me over the years wasted so much time.